# How to get params from url? or better way to do it

Tags: php, codeigniter, uri

im creating a function to delete a contact record, then once deleted go to the view company page.

so here is my controller
    public function delete($id) {

```
        if (isset($_GET["delete"]))
        {
            $this->Contacts_model->delete($id);
            $url = "/company/view/" . $cid;
            redirect($url);
        }

}
```

and here is my model

```
 public function delete($id)    
{

            $this->db->where('id', $id);
            $this->db->delete('contacts');
}
```

on my view:

```
<a href="/contacts/delete/<?php  echo $data['id']; ?>
```

which this works and will delete the contact, but obviously wont redirect to the company/view page becuase the CID isnt being passed.

i thought about adding this to the delete link

```
<a href="/contacts/delete/<?php  echo $data['id']; ?>?delete&cid=<?php  echo $data['cid']; ?>"
```

so that cid is being passed through the url. would this work some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the `cid` in the url like

```
<a href="/contacts/delete/<?php  echo $data['id']; ?>/<?php  echo $data['cid']; ?>">delete</a>
```

In your controller function get the second parameter as `$cid` or from  `uri segment`

```
public function delete($id,$cid) {
    if (isset($_GET["delete"]))
    {
        $this->Contacts_model->delete($id);
        $url = "/company/view/" . $cid;
        redirect($url);
    }

 }
```

Here is [uri segment](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html) documentation

Comment: Ah i forgot about that. im still new to frameworks. so how the heck does codeigniter know that delete/2/12  = delete/id/cid and not delete/cid/id?

Comment: nvm, i just read that document and it says its numbered from left to right. so delete/2/3 would be delete/id/cid

Comment: parameter in url after the function names will be treated as the function parameters like `controller/myfunc/a/b/c` will be treated as `function myfunc($param1,$param2,$param3){
echo $param1; //a
echo $param2; //b
echo $param3; //c
}`